# How to use functions from derived class without adding them to the base class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, interface, solid-principles

This is very likely a silly question, but I can't seem to figure out if this is at all possible and if it should actually be done.

Say some code relies a lot on using a certain virtual base class acting as an interface and then deriving several subclasses that implements the virtual methods the base class. Is it possible to use functionality not exsisting in the base class (interface) below without completely disregarding the solid principles, when the rest of the program must not see anything but the base class "interface"? Like in the example below, is it possible to use bar() from the B class inside the function that only knows of A? And should I just add bar() to the "interface" instead?

```
// Base class - "interface"
Class A
{
    public:
        virtual int foo();
}

// Derived class - implementing the "interface" + more
Class B: public A
{
    public:
        int foo();
        int bar();
}

int main()
{

    function(A); // Some magic function that would utlize the bar() method

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How could it call the `bar` member function on an `A`? Could you just make `function` take a `B`, and then just use `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: This is what private virtual functions are for. `A` can call its virtual function, that's implemented in `B`, and the private function is not accessible from outside the class.

Comment: This should do the trick:  `int B::foo() { bar(); }`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, use the `dynamic_cast` operator (but see below).  The magic function would look something like this:

```
void function(A& a)
{
  B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(&a);
  if (b)
  {
    // Object is a B...
    b->bar();
  }
  else
  {
    // fallback logic using only methods on A
  }
}
```

But be aware that many programmers consider this a code smell.  In particular, if there's no way to implement the "fallback" branch, then it suggests the function should really accept a `B` and something in the design may be amiss.  (It's hard to say when talking in such generalities, however.)  Also be aware that `dynamic_cast` can be expensive, particularly with complex class hierarchies.

If at all reasonable, it's preferable to move the `B`-specific logic into the `B` class somehow.  You might also consider making the `bar` method a member of the `A` class (`A` would provide some sensible default implementation).  Another approach might be to create a new interface to hold the `bar` method and have your function accept an object of that type.  (The `B` class would implement both `A` and the new interface.)

Comment: But if you have class C deriving B, dynamic_cast will pass for C too, but C may or may not implements bar() - how you will protect from someone passing C to function() and getting the default behavior? He will end with bar() again declared as virtual or final - to forbid the derived classes from implementing bar() by mistake and making it for "B only". The best design is to have such functions defined in base class too with clear default behavior.

Comment: As long as we follow the Liskov Substitution Principle, then passing a `C` to the function (where `C` derives from `B`) will work fine.  `C` is a `B`.

Comment: I agree that creating a new interface would be good in this case. I'm looking at a base class with 20 ish functions not counting operators and lifecycle methods though, and I'm seriously considering adding another just to maybe avoid refactoring the whole damned system. Doing as in your code example invites to breaking the open closed principle though imo